# How to manipulate svg in different file CSS

Tags: css, svg

I have a problem I don't know how to manipulate svg for example how to transform it, if file is in other directory, not in the HTML file.

I attach img how I linked it and my directories

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  An SVG linked to with `<img>` is effectively loaded and presented on the page as if it was a bitmap (like a PNG etc).  It must be inline if you want to manipulate it.